# How to extend application hang timeout?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I have a legacy application, which processes user input data. The app crashes on one machine without warning, the problem doesn't appear for all other users. I asked user to send me screenshot of his Event Viewer, because AppDomain UnhandledException event didn't produce any popup message. The error I got is:

> The program <appname> stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in Security and Maintenence control panel.

Event ID is 1002, I read that I should move most time-consuming operations to background thread, but application is just too big to refactor it in less than week.

Is there any way to allow very long UI hangs for this application? I mean more than 5 minutes

Comment: Your processing function should be async to avoid that problem. When handling lots of data in the mainthread it will freeze and not respond to windows for as long as the function is running.

Comment: Yup, that's a long-term solution, but currently I have large application written in .net 2.0, so I can't provide help quickly. Is there something I can do quickly, like change windows configuration?

Comment: check my answer :-)

Comment: If you decided not to do it the right way from the beginning then you simply have to face the consequences of your actions and take the time necessary to update your code. There is no good workaround or "quick fix" to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this post](https://tweaks.com/windows/37052/modify-application-timeout/) on [Tweaks.com](https://tweaks.com/)

> The operating system has a set amount of time that a program must be
>   frozen for before it is timed out.  Often this number is set too high.
>   But in some circumstances it is set too low.  Depending on if the
>   program is doing a lot of calculations in the background the computer
>   may think that it is timed out. To prevent this increase the value of
>   the timeout in the registry.
>
> 1. Start Regedit.  If you are unfamiliar with regedit please refer to our FAQ on how to get started.
> 2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
> 3. Select HungAppTimeout from the list on the right.
> 4. Right on it and select Modify.
> 5. Change the value to the new timeout value.
> 6. Reboot your computer.

---

Edit 1:

Unfortunatly this might not work on Windows 10 as this was posted for Windows XP.

---

Edit 2:

According to [this post](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97842-change-hungapptimeout-value-windows-10-a.html) on [tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/) this might still work.

> When apps (tasks) do not end (close) automatically when you are
>   restarting, shutting down, or signing out of Windows 10, the system
>   will wait 5 seconds (HungAppTimeout) by default before the End Task
>   dialog appears asking you to cancel or to close the listed apps and
>   restart anyway, shut down anyway, or sign out anyway.
>
> If you do not make a choice in the End Task dialog before the 1 minute
>   timeout expires, Windows 10 will automatically cancel the restart,
>   shutdown, or sign-out by default.
>
> For example, if you have notepad open with unsaved changes when you
>   restart, shut down, or sign out.
>
> HungAppTimeout also specifies how long (5 seconds by default) the
>   system waits for user processes to end after the user clicks/taps on
>   the End task button in Task Manager. If this threshold is exceeded,
>   the End Task dialog box appears, stating that the process did not
>   respond.
>
> This tutorial will show you how to specify the HungAppTimeout value
>   for how long the system waits before the End Task dialog appears for
>   your account or all users in Windows 10.

---

You should try it. You will most likely find a ̶s̶̶o̶̶l̶̶u̶̶t̶̶i̶̶o̶̶n̶  workaround.

Keep in mind that this is not a long time solution. You will need to move that code into a backroundthread.

Note: I would not recommend changing these values programmatically. Avoid implementing workarounds in your code.

As VisualVincent pointed out (thanks!) you should also remember to change those values back to its originals as soon as you release the fix.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a solution but rather a really dirty workaround. Changing this on the users' computers is _**definitely not good**_ as it affects all applications! If the OP didn't do it right in the beginning by using multithreading then he has to face the consequences and take the time necessary to fix it.

Comment: @VisualVincent If you work in a small programming company you will know, that you sometimes do need those quick workarounds. If you are working on grown applications you will also know, that completly rewriting code is something that needs time. If your application is needed but not running on a customers computer you do want to have a quick workaround until you have been able to fix the source behind it. There is nothing wrong with it as long as you fix the code in the end.

Comment: @VisualVincent just to make it more clear to you: If your customer needs your application and can't work when it's not running, then you do need to find a quick solution. If your customer cant work for a whole week because of your application, then you will probably lose that customer. To avoid that you need to abuse workarounds sometimes. Surely workarounds are not the nice way, but the most important thing for a company is to keep their customers. Even if that means that some tasks have to be done a little dirty until it's fixed. You won't find textbook programming in small servicecompanies.

Comment: I know that very well, thank you. However requiring the customer to change registry-accessible Windows settings to make your application work is indicates a _really_ bad design and is definitely not a good thing to have them do (or to have your application do, for that matter). What if the customer isn't tech-savvy enough to do it, or to remember to change it back when the code is fixed? Also _(I certainly **don't** know this for sure, but)_ I don't see this application having a proper commercial customer base if the people behind it don't know how to utilize something as basic as threads.

Comment: Workarounds aren't necessarily bad, but when it comes to modifying registry entries that affect the entire system it certainly isn't a good option. Anyway I am willing to retract my downvote after your edit as it at least indicates that this way is not preferred. Though you might want to add what I said in my previous comment: He needs to make sure that the value is reset when the code is fixed (either by the customer or by his app, and _only_ if it has been changed by/for his app).

Comment: @VisualVincent I started my career as the only developer of my company right after my vocational training. One of my first applications ever written for a customer has now more than 50.000 lines of code and contains tons of 'beginner mistakes'. This app is now used by about 300 employee and is their base - They can't work without it. I would love to fix them all, but when you are working in a service company you simply can't. As long as the app works the customer will not be willing to pay you for back-end for changes-That means you are not authorized to do it as long as there is no contract.

Comment: +1 for your edit (forgot to check it earlier). I feel it makes the answer more complete as it both answers the question and also points out the do's and don'ts regarding the temporary solution. -- I'd also like to apologize for my grumpy behaviour earlier. I was very rude and arrogant against you. I'm actually not sure why I felt that way, but I definitely shouldn't have let it out on you. So for that I am sincerely sorry. You were only trying to help and I praise you for that!

Comment: @VisualVincent That's totally fine. In the end you helped me to improve the answer - Because your points weren't wrong! We both helped Matt1990 , and that's what we are here for, isn't it? - Chat over :-)